# Mailgun message in Golang not send under cronjob

Tags: go, mailgun

I have created a go application that at a certain point send a email via Mailgun. If I run my application under Linux with ./testApp it works fine.

But if I run exact the same application under a cronjob it does not work, it is not sending any emails.
*/1 * * * * /home/bin/testApp

In the application i use the standard sending code, see below:

```
mg := mailgun.NewMailgun(yourMarketingDomain, privateAPIKey)
mg.SetAPIBase(mailgun.APIBaseEU)
message := mg.NewMessage(email)
message.SetHtml(body.String())
message.SetReplyTo(email)
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
defer cancel()
_, trackcode, _ := mg.Send(ctx, message)
```

It is not send, and no trackcode is returned.

Any idee's?

Comment: Is this your real code? You seem to explicitly ignore the error from `mg.Send`. If so, what are we talking about?

Comment: Are you using a `.env`/configuration file that doesn't exist in /home/bin?

Comment: It is real code, just a bit simplified. I added the err response from Mailgun, I'm getting "message not valid". That is strange because when i run it directly i'm not getting this error.

Comment: Problem found, is not releated to mailgun but to the linux user that is defferent. Please remove this question.